# How to modify XMPP requests

Tags: erlang, xmpp, chat, ejabberd, whatsapp

I am new in XMPP. I have installed basic ejabberd in my server. I am writing code for app on client side. As we know there are lots of standard stanza's in XMPP and they further have many types and attributes. I want to hide the details of those stanza's so that user can not find out the details of requests. For example, if I am creating a chat room with some configurations ( 10 -20 standard variables which can be passed to create a room) then I dont want to show the default values of some variables (because they will be same for all). In summary, I want to modify the XMPP request before it delivers to the XMPP server (according to my need). These modifications should also take place at server side only. This is something WhatsApp is doing. Is there any way to do this ?

(App)  ---request--->  (XMPP Server)    [standard way]

(App)  ------modified XMPP Request----> (Some Program) ---Convert into standard request---> (XMPP Server)      [Something I want]

Here, (Some Program) and (XMPP Server) will be on same server.

Comment: why don't you let `Some Program` act as a server to your app and as a client to the XMPP Server ? Of course, you'll need to be quite careful with your program in that case not to create a bottleneck but I don't see the issue here.

Comment: @MattKo in that case I will not be able to use the advantages of XMPP.

Comment: well that really depends. I didn't mean client in the sense that your program is a user of your XMPP domain and you send all messages as that user. I was more thinking about a middleware acting as a translator between clients and your XMPP server. It's still a client to the XMPP server in the sense of the client-server-model though.

Comment: On top of that, there are certain advantages of a protocol which you simply cannot have if you start changing that protocol. Your clients are already out of the standard XMPP protocol since they're not sending XMPP messages, so obviously, they won't be able to talk to standard XMPP servers, for example, which is one advantage of XMPP. Maybe you should define what advantages you want to have and which ones you don't care about ?